# is it possible for an xcode macOS sdk to be installed without IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

I am working with xcode on a public mac computer. Strangely when I try to install phonegap, which requires the IOS SDK, it comes up with nothing. I thought that xcode installations always came with both the macOS SDK and the IOS sdk?

this is for snow leopard, what is going on here?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have? Who installed it? What does "it comes up with nothing" mean?

Comment: @bneely i have xcode 3.2.6 and by nothing i mean its not installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible to only install the Mac dev tools, but you can download the iOS SDK from within Xcode:

Just go to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and look in the Components tab to see what's installed. If the iOS simulator and debugging support aren't installed you can just download them.

If you can't find those options, check the version of Xcode in Xcode > About Xcode. If it's less than 4 you'll probably want to download the latest and reinstall it anyway.

Comment: ijust checked it and it looks like my xcode 3.2.6 doesn't have the IOS option in the updates. The problem is that I can't install a new version since this is a public lab. However, it does provide the option to add publisher source, maybe theres an unknown source i could reference to?

Comment: I believe that for Xcode 3.2.6, the iOS and MAC OS Xcode installs were completely separate, so you won't be able to install just the iOS components. However, if you don't have the admin rights to install a new Xcode version, it's unlikely that you have the rights to install the iOS components anyway. And Xcode 3.2.6 is most likely incompatible with the latest iOS SDK. I think you'll have to find someone who can upgrade it for you.